# Stop videos from autostart in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm working on Django where I need to show more than one video in one page. Can anyone help me to stop autostart on my videos in `iframe`.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="1280" height="720" src="/static/assets/img/examples/vi.mp4?&autoPlay=0" frameborder="0" &autoPlay="false"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `autoplay` attribute since the browser will play it as soon as it sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `autoPlay="false"` attribute use `autostart = "false"`

like this:-

```
<source src="html/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" autostart="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your video to autoplay ,
then you can use `autoplay=0` insted of `autoplay=false`